# Nougat device crashes, Marshmallow doesn't - NullPointerException on MenuItem

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-7.0-nougat

I've been developing an app in a Marshmallow 6.0 phone. Today, I ran it in a Nougat 7.0 phone and everything was ok. Changed one line of xml code ('selectableItemBackground' to 'selectableItemBackgroundBorderless' in a LinearLayout) and got an NPE on an unrelated MenuItem ("Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.MenuItem.setIcon(int)' on a null object reference") here:

```
public void updateSpeakerIcon() {
        if (mIsSpeakerOn) {
            mSpeakerIcon.setIcon(R.drawable.speaker);
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        } else {
            mSpeakerIcon.setIcon(R.drawable.earphone);
            setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL);
        }
    }
```

I'm using a ViewPager; this method is declared in the activity that contains it; the fragments call this method in their onResume callback.

mSpeakerIcon is 'found' in the onCreateOptionsMenu callback, in the same activity:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.qmenu, menu);
        mSpeakerIcon = menu.findItem(R.id.toggle_speaker);
        return true;
    }
```

I've changed the one line back to what it was but, of course, it did not fix the problem. Ran the app once again in the 6.0 device and there's no error.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you calling `updateSpeakerIcon()`? It would appear that it is before `onCreateOptionsMenu()` gets called.

Comment: The fragments call this method in their onResume callback. Wouldn't that also be an issue in the Marshmallow device?

Comment: Not necessarily. `onCreateOptionsMenu()` has no guarantees in terms of timing with respect to lifecycle methods like `onResume()`. So, the rules there can change between OS versions.